# Pass Java Script var to PHP $var

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How can I pass my javascript variables to my PHP scripts, without reloading webpage or using separated PHP script through AJAX or javascript itself?

Comment: `$POST_` you realize that that is a major syntax error. You're putting the horse behind the wagon, as it were.

Comment: You're also assigning `if(var =` rather than comparing `if(var ==`

Comment: and now you're editing "on the fly"..;. well I have to run now. Comments above as per the original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40363160/1

Comment: Provide a lot more detail please

Comment: Store the `$_POST` variable on the first submission and reuse.  For instance `session_start(); $_SESSION[ 'post' ] = $_POST[ 'var' ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reloading your browser you can use javascript

put this before the `<body>` tag

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#varbtn").click(function(){
        var var1 = $("#var").val();

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "post.php",
                data: {
                    var:var1
                    },
                success: function(data){
                //#success will be the id of the div you want to put the response of the php file
                    $("#success").html(data);
                }
            });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

in the form, you dont need to create `<form>` tag

```
<input type="text id="var" />
<button id="varbtn"> Submit</button>

<!--this div will be the result of the post.php file-->
<div id="success"></div>
```

in the post.php

```
//will check if the person will direct visit that post.php, this is not secured enough but hes doing his job actually 
<?php 
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    if(!isset($_POST['var'])){
        //your codes here
    }
}
?>
```